# How to view(display) stream of data(base64)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have stream of data(base64).it can be PDF or image(jpeg, ,png).on click of the button if it is PDF base64 then it should open with adobe pdf reader or if it is png data then it should open with window's default or any viewer which exit on the system.

```
public download(data: any) {
const dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
saveAs(dataURI, 'scene.png');
}
```

I have a two scenario's one is **download** and other is **view**
The above code will work for download,

For view i wanna display the same file in the browser.

Example: If it is an image the same image should display in the browser.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I have tried to search throughout but everywhere I have found related to window.location and window.open, That is not I want .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].